# JSON document size reduction without changing it's structure

Tags: json, encoding, compression, azure-cosmosdb

### Problem -

We do store dynamic JSON document in Cosmos-DB. We want to reduce document size without loosing search capabilities provided by Cosmos-DB.

### Solution -

Thinking about selective key encoding of JSON key fields.

Why selective ?  because key space is not fixed. So if we will start encoding all kind of keys then our encoding dictionary might take more then 2 MB space (or we can not control how much space it is going to take) which might create other problems.

### For example –

Original Document -

```
“sample-key-name”: {
      “sample-sub-key-one”: “I am value one”,
      “sample-sub-key-two”: “I am value two”,
      “sample-sub-key-three”: “I am value three”
}
```

Document After Encoding –

```
“a”: {
  “k1”: “I am value one”,
  “k2”: “I am value two”,
  “K3”: “I am value three”
}
```

Dictionary : -

```
{
  “a”: “sample-key-name”,
 “k1”: “sample-sub-key-one”,
 “k2”: “sample-sub-key-two”,
 “k3”: “sample-sub-key-three”
}
```

Why are we not encoding complete JSON doc ? We will loose ability to search

What else could be explored/tried/used/done to make it more elegant (considering JSON doc is dynamic) ?

In one similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934018/can-keys-in-json-document-be-compressed-in-cosmos-db) data migration to cheap storage is advised, we have already implemented it. But on top of it we want to save cost for CosmosDB as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic, as it's very broad and opinion-based; this really is up to you. There are no absolutes regarding how to compress your data (and whether it's going to be advantageous to you, ). Seems like you're making more work for yourself though, given that you have to maintain a translation layer for property names.

Comment: If you're worried that you design might result in documents > 2MB in size I would revisit it. You very much want to avoid unbounded arrays in your design. These result in poor performance as the document size grows, and can result in exceptions when you try to write it back over 2MB in size. Also this notion of using symbols for your property names that map to actual names, is also only something that makes an impact at extremely large volumes for storage. I would normally not bother with it.